# Changing row colors in the Compact Framework DataGrid

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

How can I use non-default coloring in the DataGrid control in a Windows CE compact framework application?

I need to color one row in color X and one row in color Y (alternating row colors basically).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paint datagrid row in color in WinCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504558/paint-datagrid-row-in-color-in-wince)

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to manually do custom drawing.  Ilya on the CF team has a straightforward example of doing it [on the team blog here](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx).

Comment: I've tried to find the source in any archive, but can't.  it's lost to the depths of MSDNs black hole I guess.