# Paint datagrid row in color in WinCE

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

how can I paint all rows in a datagrid with the value of field "age" = 30 in red?

I work in WinCE.

*Thanks for any help!*

Comment: The answer hasn't changed since [the last time you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408113/changing-row-colors-in-the-compact-framework-datagrid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like. I set

`Datagrid1.Datasource = Datatable1.DefaultView`

where Datatable1 is a Datatable that contains a column named "Age"

Sorry, is in VB

Private Sub paintColors()

```
    Dim vI As Int64 
    DataGrid1.SelectionBackColor = Color.OrangeRed
    Dim vI As Int64 = 0
    For vI = 0 To Datatable1.DefaultView.Count - 1

        If Datatable1.DefaultView.Item(vI)("Age") = 30 Then
            DataGrid1.Select(vI)
        Else
            DataGrid1.UnSelect(vI)
        End If

    Next
```

End Sub

Comment: How can I prevent the user from changing the background color by clicking on a cell? I tried to set Enabled to false but, the user cannot scroll around the grid now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going back to the example ctacke linked to and specifically looking at:

```
DataGridCustomColumnBase.DrawBackground
```

There it supports colouring a row in a particular colour for alternative rows. Once you've understood this **in** **its** **entirity** it shouldn't be too hard to paint them whatever colour you want whenever you want.

The example code is so awesome that you could play with the full framework and then port your knowledge (as the guy has made his code cross-compatible with the CF <-> FF) to CF. Re-read and grok that example because it is a very nice one.

Comment: Ilya is nothing if not thorough.