# Font color of a row in DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, compact-framework, row, windows-mobile-6.5

How can I change the font color of a row in DataGrid?

The color depends on a condition in the table.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504558/paint-datagrid-row-in-color-in-wince) post here on stackflow but it works only for the selected lines, and that the line would be another color, regardless of being selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an event handler to the grid view's `Paint`.

If you want to do more than just the colour, we have gone the route of inheriting from `DataGridViewCell` and overriding its Paint method, inheriting from `DataGridViewColumn` to use that cell, then use that column in our grid view.

Below is the overridden method, but the event hander would look similar.

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics,
            Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds,
            int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object
            formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
            DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts
            paintParts)
        {
             if ((value as WhatEverType).WhatEverField == 9)
             {
                 cellStyle.ForeColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
             }
             base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        }
```

Comment: I do not understand.
I will create a class, inherit it from DataGridViewCell and override the Paint .. but then what?

Comment: Remember that I am developing in the environment Compact Framework (Windows Mobile)

Comment: Probably you just need to add an event handler, but if you want to inherit, you inherit a cell that paints the way you want, you inherit a column that uses your cell, and you use that column in your grid view.  Probably overkill for a font colour change, but we were doing all sort of other things as well.  I'm not sure whether any of this is avaialable for Windows Mobile.