# Is there any way to show CheckBox in DataGrid

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there any way to show CheckBox in DataGrid in my C# program on Windows-Mobile (FW 3.5)?

Comment: Yes. Yes there is. Please go on to describe exactly why you are having trouble achieving this?

Comment: i work on Windows-Mobile and i don't see any way - how you can do it ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is the same as [when you asked about changing row colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408113/changing-row-colors-in-the-compact-framework-datagrid).  Yes, you can do it by custom drawing.